# Showing first picture in each category on Rails app index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce

I'm learning Rails by building a small personal Ecommerce App.

So far I have built a products page, category page, checkout page and so on.

I´m able to upload pictures and assign them to categories through this product_form.

```
<%= form_for @product, multipart: true do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :image %><br>
 <%= f.file_field :image %>
```

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category %><br>
  <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] } %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
 <% end %>
```

Then, I can go to each category by selecting it in the _navbar.html.erb, like this.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">                 
         <% @categories.each do |category| %>
           <li><%= link_to category.name, category %></li>
         <% end %>    
  </ul>
```

But the thing I want to be able to do is to display the latest uploaded picture in each category on the index page `views/pages/index.html.erb` so each picture will appear in its own div in a Bootstrap grid.

I´m not sure how to do that.

This is what I have come up with so far, by displaying this code in the in `views/pages/index.html.erb`

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

<%= image_tag product.image, height: "300", class: "img-responsive" %>


  <div class="product_description">

     <h5><%= link_to product.name, product %></h5>
     <p><%= product.description %></p>
     <p class="price"> <%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>

   </div>


   </div>
 <% end %>
```

and in the `pages_controller.rb` I have

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @products = Product.all
   end
end
```

so my question is, how should I change the controller or the `views/pages/index.html.erb` to be able to only show the last uploaded picture in each category on the  `views/pages/index.html.erb`

**EDIT**

this is the product part of the schema file

```
 create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.string   "description"
   t.float    "price"
   t.string   "image"
   t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
   t.integer  "category_id", default: 1
 end
```

this is the category.rb model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end
```

thanks in advance
D

Answer (score 1):

List item

---

You need to first make Product Category association.
For Eg:

> Category has many products

.
So in your Product table you can have category_id foreign key. So each product will be assigned with some category_id.
Now you can do:
In your Products controller:

```
@products = Product.all.order('created_at DESC').group_by(:category_id)
```

In your Product view:

```
@products.each do |product|
 image_tag product.image.url(:thumb)
 product.name
 product.category.name
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SnehaT  This works in a way, but when I add the `.group_by(:category_id)` ending to the product variable it gives me a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error, why is that? but if I only use `Product.all.order(created_at: :desc)´ the variable works.  I have the `has_ many` association in the `category.rb`model and the schema file for the product table has this line `t.integer  "category_id", default: 1` is the default 1 maybe causing this to fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your navbar.html.erb file.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">                 
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to category.name, category %>
            <%= image_tag(category.images.last) %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the query someway like this:
@prods = Product.all.order('created_at DESC')
@products = @prods.group_by { |p| p.category_id }

May be this will work